# Auto respond 'yes' for 'grails war' on Hudson

Tags: plugins, grails, continuous-integration, hudson

We're using 'grails war' to build a war on hudson then another job to deploy to our test environment.

The problem is that when the 'grails war' encounters a plugin upgrade, it will continuously ask the user to upgrade certain plugins.

Is there a way to respond 'y' on all user input?

I tried --non-interactive but that seems to do nothing.

Comment: I think the Catholic church needs to be involved in this one, and you may need to start a crusade. Though I didn't know that the grail had been spotted in Hudson Bay.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may need to put quotes around the run target in the Targets text field:

```
"war --non-interactive"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
yes | grails war
```

assuming your on OSX/unix/Linux/cygwin.  That answers yes for all questions that the program you pipe it to asks.

if you only want to say yes once, you can use

```
echo y | grails war
```

Comment: This is for the hudson job, not command line in terminal.  I need a way to configure the hudson grails build to do this.

Comment: @Matthew Boston - Doesn't Hudson allow you to specify build steps that use shell commands?

Comment: Yes, but then you have to define the location where you'll be running the command and will not have the ability to define which grails version to use.