# How to respond to console output in Hudson

Tags: grails, hudson, jenkins

My hudson build is failing as while building it asks to upgrade plugin with y/n how can i respond with no over here ?

```
Environment set to ci
Upgrading plugin [codenarc-0.8] to [codenarc-0.9]. ...
Resolving new plugins. Please wait... ...
You currently already have a version of the plugin installed [codenarc-0.8]. Do you want to upgrade this version? [y,n] 
Invalid option 'null' - must be one of: [y,n]

You currently already have a version of the plugin installed [codenarc-0.8]. Do you want to upgrade this version? [y,n] 
Invalid option 'null' - must be one of: [y,n]

You currently already have a version of the plugin installed [codenarc-0.8]. Do you want to upgrade this version? [y,n] 
Invalid option 'null' - must be one of: [y,n]

No valid response entered - giving up asking.
Plugin codenarc-0.9 install aborted
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly you can specify a `--non-interactive` flag with the `grails` command to disable user prompts.

Comment: [Same answer in identical question][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899504/auto-respond-yes-for-grails-war-on-hudson

Answer (score 0):

Hudson does not seem to respect the no-interactive for plugins. Go to the grails folder

usually ~/.grails/projects/ and delete everything to start new.